# Identify Sequence of Events In BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I needed help with some logic for the following dataset:

```
ID | POST10 | EVENTS_TIMESTAMP |
1  | picked | 2022.11.06 1:00pm|
1  | profile| 2022.11.06 1:30pm| 
1  | front  | 2022.11.06 1:35pm|

2  | profile| 2022.11.06 1:00pm|
2  | profile| 2022.11.06 1:30pm| 
2  | front  | 2022.11.06 1:35pm|
2  | front  | 2022.11.06 1:36pm|

3  | picked | 2022.11.06 1:00pm|
3  | front  | 2022.11.06 1:30pm| 
3  | profile| 2022.11.06 1:35pm|
3  | front  | 2022.11.06 1:36pm|
```

**LOGIC SHOULD BE:**

FOR A PERSON, **FIRST VALUE SHOULD BE "picked"**, **THEN "profile"** AND **IN BETWEEN THOSE TWO VALUES**, "front" did not occur.** It can occur after or before those two(based on timestamp) but not in between.

**ANSWER FOR THE DATASET ABOVE WOULD BE:**

```
ID | ANSWER      |
1  | SELECTED    | 
2  | NOT SELECTED| 
3  | NOT SELECTED|
```

I wrote the sql but the greater/less than(<,>) arnt working as expected. It looks at the second part after **AND** individually. I need it to look inside the same window between **picked** and **profile**

```
(case when  
(min(case when (post10) like '%picked%' then EVENTS_TIMESTAMP else null end) over (partition by (ID)) 
>= 
 min(case when (post10) like '%profile%' then EVENTS_TIMESTAMP else null end) over (partition by (ID)))
 AND
 (min(case when (post10) like '%profile%' then EVENTS_TIMESTAMP else null end) over (partition by (ID))
 >= 
 min(case when (post10) like '%front%' then EVENTS_TIMESTAMP else null end) over (partition by (ID)))
then 'SELECTED'
else 'NOT SELECTED' end) as ANSWER
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below

```sql
SELECT ID, IF(COUNTIF(flag) > 0, 'SELECT', 'NOT SELECTED') AS ANSWER 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, POST10 = 'picked' AND LEAD(POST10) OVER w = 'profile' AS flag
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PARSE_DATETIME('%Y.%m.%d %l:%M%p', EVENT_TIMESTAMP))
  )
 GROUP BY ID;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Lead function is a good use in this case. Thank you!